# Thinking Sphinx delta indexing - delta index not getting updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have delta indexing setup for thinking sphinx on one of my models. When ever a record gets updated, the delta is being set to True, but I don't see the index getting updated with the changes made to the record. I have my sphinx configuration files updated with the delta property changes. Any idea why the delta indexing is not getting triggered?

Answer (score -2):

According to the documentation after you update the database and the model, you should do this:

rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild

Maybe you've omit that step..